# Prestashop Filters 'display' => 'full' working for Customer resource and not for product and orders

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

To retrieve data from Prestashop using Webservice we use:

```
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($prestashopstoreurl, $prestashopApiKey, true);

$opt['resource'] = 'orders';
$opt['display']='full';     

$xml=$webService->get($opt);
```

But  'display' => 'full' filter is not get applied on products and sales orders resource but working for the customer resource.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Four of your last six questions have needed substantial code-formatting repair in order to be readable. Please take a moment [to read how to format code here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+format+code+on+stack+overflow) before asking more questions, to reduce the amount of administrative work required.